# Communicating between different components which doesnt have a parent-child relationship in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lets say i have 2 different DOM elements

```
<div id="firstDiv">
</div>
<div id="secondDiv">
</div>
```

Now lets say i render some html inside the ***firstDiv*** using

```
React.render(firstComponent(null),document.getElementById('firstDiv');
```

Now lets say i fetch some data from a server inside the firstComponent and then i gotto render part of the data inside ***secondDiv*** , whats the best way to do it ??Can i call **React.renderComponent(,document.getElementById("secondDiv"))** from inside the firstComponent ?? And how to achieve a two-way communication between them ??? Lets say now i click a link in the html rendered in the secondDiv then how to change the text inside the firstDiv ??

If i generalize this question it would be "How do i render html inside multiple DOM elements from one single component and then communicate across these components which are rendered in different DOM elements???"

Comment: Here is a good read: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html

Comment: @David : Thank you , the last paragraph in the webpage was helpful -  "For communication between two components that don't have a parent-child relationship, you can set up your own global event system. Subscribe to events in componentDidMount(), unsubscribe in componentWillUnmount(), and when you receive an event, call setState()"

Comment: The quote KarthicRao has mentioned is not in the link @David sent. It's now changed to ... http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by regular [parent-child communication](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html), except in this case you do not have any parent.

But you can still pass to the root component some functions that will be called inside the 2 components and trigger the rendering

Here is a working demo of the exemple you asked:

```
var First = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>Hello1 {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
});


var Second = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div onClick={this.props.onSecondClicked}>Hello2 {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
});

function onSecondClicked() {
    React.render(<First name="World updated!" />, document.getElementById("first"));
}

React.render(<First name="World" />, document.getElementById("first"));

React.render(<Second name="World" onSecondClicked={onSecondClicked}/>, document.getElementById("second"));
```

[JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/6958/)

---

Calling `React.render` inside the 2nd component should normally work (maybe not during during the render phase but this is not a good idea anyway). However it creates a huge coupling between your 2 components.

You can also create a "root component" that will be a parent of the 2 components.

If you have a lot of components to synchronize, you may use an event bus for cross-component communication.

Comment: Thanks a lot .... Yes as you mentioned it becomes difficult to synchronize when lot of components are involved . Can you give me some idea about how to setup an event bus for cross-component communication for the above case ?

Comment: You can easily create one. An event bus is just an object with a `publishEvent` method and an array of listeners. You can also use an open source and more advanced js bus like https://github.com/postaljs/postal.js

Comment: All your "root components" should listen to the event bus and change their React state according to events, propagation this state to their childs with props.

Answer (score 1):

This comment was too long to fit inside a comment, so that's why i'm pulling it out here.

I think you should take a look at Flux architecture what Facebook uses internally to manage their React apps, and which is now opensourced. Inside Flux, your case would be as follows:

- when `firstComponent` is rendered (mounted) you deliver an action to the store (*container for your application/domain state*) to indicate that the store should initially pull the data from the server. When the data is available the Store would emit a (**change**) event, that *"hey, I fetched the data successfully, you can come and get it"*
- Both of your component already set up a change listener to the store, so when the store emitted the change event, your components will demand the new data, by calling a getter on the store (e.g `getState()`). Both of your components would render only that part of the data, what they are interested in.
- When in `secondComponent` an action happens (say an onClick) which would alter the state of the application, this action (web API event) would trigger a Flux Action (a plain old JS helper method) which will end in the Store modifying the state. (there's a dispatcher in the chain, among others i'm not talking about now)

  - The store would change it's initial state to the new one, say from `Hello World` to `Hello, World! I'm updated`.
  - Upon state change, the store emits a change event again, and your first component updates its state accordingly.

Comment: Maybe for this simple example Flux,  and Flux's boilerplate seems a little overhead, but Flux, and unidirectional data flow shines when your app grows large and became more complicated.